# Why is my mapped user not able to use the password in .pgpass? - Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a `FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER` and access the `admin` user with a password that is held in my `.pgpass`. Here is the code that I am using to create the wrapper:

```
create extension postgres_fdw;

CREATE SERVER source FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host 'test.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com', dbname 'test', port '5432');


CREATE USER MAPPING FOR CURRENT_USER
    SERVER source
    OPTIONS (user 'admin');

CREATE SCHEMA app;

IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public
    FROM SERVER source
    INTO app;
```

My `.pgpass` has this value in it

```
test.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432:test:admin:password
```

My statement fails each time when I try to import the schema. If I add the password to the `USER MAPPING`, then the connection works fine and there are no issues. What do I need to change to be able to make this connection?

Answer (score 2):

If `.pgpass` is used, it would be the `.pgpass` file held in the home directory of the OS user who owns the PostgreSQL server process, not of the account running the client process.  To prevent you from using someone else's password without permission, this will only work if you are the superuser, or if the user mapping was created by a superuser and had `password_required` set to `false` (and this latter option only works from v13).

There is no provision to proxy the client's `.pgpass` through for use on the server.